# Is it possible to define a macro for major minor build revision?

Tags: visual-c++

I am building a C++ DLL in Visual C++ and would like to append the file version number from the resource file to the resulting DLL name to allow multiple DLL versions to exist in a single folder. i.e.:

```
MyDLL.1.0.3.44.dll
MyDLL.1.0.3.45.dll
```

I can't seem to find a macro for the version and therefore cannot programmatically set the output file name.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: macros are at source level, DLL version numbers at binary level. So do it the other way, define yourself macros for your version numbers.

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio, have you tried using a post build step? The step could read the version number and rename the file.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think this is very close, however I can't seem to get past a) the difference between the dot and comma delimited version number strings and b) resource compiler not liking a macro for version number. It explicitly wants 4 comma separated DWORDs.